# Numerical methods for linear system of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem, bifurcation

I have the following linear ordinary differential problem

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
EI y'''' - \left[M_z(z) x'\right]'' - \left[ T(z)y'\right]' = -\alpha y \\
EI x'''' - \left[M_z(z) y'\right]'' - \left[ T(z)x'\right]' = -\alpha x
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

where

$$
M_z(z) = M_0 = const \quad \quad \text{and} \quad \quad  T(z) = -T_0\left(1-\tfrac{z}{Z}\right)
$$

The $'$ denotes differentiation with respect to  $z$.
This system has to be solved for $z \in \left[0, Z\right] $ with the following conditions:

$$
\begin{cases}
x = y = x'' = y'' = 0 \quad \text{at}\,\, z=0 \\
x = y = x' = y' = 0 \quad \text{at}\,\, z=Z 
\end{cases}
$$

Then, in matricial form one can rewrite it as

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
Y' = MY \\
f(Y(0)) = 0 \\
g(Y(Z)) = 0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

where $Y = \left( y, y', y'', y''', x, x', x'', x''' \right)$ and

$$
f(\mathbf{v}) = \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_3 \\ v_5 \\ v_7 \end{pmatrix}
\quad \quad
g(\mathbf{v}) = \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \\ v_5 \\ v_6 \end{pmatrix}
$$

Of course, there is always the trivial solution $Y=0$, but there should be non trivial solutions that at the moment I am not able to catch (by simply using a method like the bvp4 provided by MATLAB/python). Any suggestion?

Comment: Exactly! But  can the shooting method be applied in this situation? I knew it was for second order boundary value problems

Comment: A quick [search](https://scholar.google.fr/scholar?hl=fr&as_sdt=0%2C5&q="two-point+boundary+value+problem"&btnG=) with the keyword *two-point boundary value problem* tells that there must be such methods.